# Legal Issues around simulated phishing attacks

Tags: phishing, legal

We are putting together a service for use both internally and for our clients using GoPhish to test users' awareness of phishing. Basically, the users will receive a phishing email and we will measure how many users open the email, click links, and disclose information.

I have two concerns from a legal perspective (we are based in the UK and only have UK based clients).

1) If I put together an email that looks like it comes from Amazon, could they sue me for using their brand without permission?

2) In order to conduct the campaign we will need to store users' names, email addresses and other information. Once GDPR comes into effect we would need consent to store these details (AFAIK), but if we ask the user first that defeats the objective. Is there any way around this restriction?

Comment: Since these are purely legal question they are off-topic. Please try at law.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1):

As the author of SelfPhish, I can weigh in on some things that might help without offering legal advice.

1. Using a company's logo without permission is always a problem. But why use another company's logo and site? Why not use a site for which you *can* get permission? Like your own site or the site of your clients?
2. What's your objective? Will you not announce to the users that you will be phishing them? If you are planning to not do this, you are in trouble from an education standpoint anyway. Do not use phishing as a predatory activity; it should be an education and awareness activity, and that means telling them what you are going to do. Surprises will only result in problems and complaints.

In general, I don't think you have thought through this service and what you hope to achieve. If you want to show users how stupid they are, then you are on the right track, but the value of this activity is dubious. You need to treat this as an education activity, and education requires participation, not entrapment.

Comment: + 1000. The human interaction in such cases (letting them know that tests will occur in a near future) is very, very important. If you plan to do an awareness session on that topic, try to make it so your users will not avoid or consider suspicious EVERY email - could backfire

Answer (score -1):

I am not a law expert.  But I suggest you check your local cyber security rules and law on "research", which might waive the liabilities, not on abuse of brand, but the phishing simulation.

1. Make Spear phishing your primary phishing criteria. Because it is an explicit target social engineering attack.
2. Make well known brand phishing (e.g. DHL, Amazon) as secondary criteria and be creative. You don't need a 100% looks alike phishing page.